# Time comparing on debug mode and release mode(Visual studio 2008)

Tags: c++

I implemented A* and JPS(Jump Point Search) using VS2008. 
Then i tried comparing time cost of these code.

On debug mode, (my) JPS is faster than A* about 2.0~50 times .
But on release mode, JPS is faster than A* about 0.6~3.0 times.
Especially, almost cases of test on release mode, JPS slower than A*.

Why results are so different?
In the paper( "Online Graph Pruning for Pathfinding on Grid Maps", 2011 ), 
JPS is faster than A* about 20~30 times.
If i want to get a similar results in the paper, what should i do?

I just call map1.A_star() and map2.JPS() in main.cpp.
and I used prioiry_queue(STL) for A* and JPS.

↓ pathfinding.cpp

```
#include "util.h"

using namespace std;


int DIR_X[8] = { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1 };
int DIR_Y[8] = { -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1 };
// diagonal index {1, 3, 5, 7}

template<class T>
void vector_clear(vector<T>& vecObj)
{
    vector<T> tempObj;
    tempObj.swap(vecObj);
}



bool operator<(const Node& a, const Node& b)
{
    return a.getPriority() > b.getPriority();
}

void read_scenario(char* path, char(*scenarios)[256], int& total) {

    ifstream scen_file(path);
    char buffer[256];
    int num = 0;
    scen_file.getline(buffer, 256);


    while (!scen_file.eof()) {
        scen_file.getline(buffer, 256);
        num++;
        int index1;
        int index2;
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i<256; i++) {
            if (buffer[i] == ' ')
                count++;

            if (buffer[i] == ' ' && count == 4)
                index1 = i;

            if (buffer[i] == ' ' && count == 8)
                index2 = i;

        }

        for (int i = index1 + 1; i <= index2 - 1; i++) {
            scenarios[num][i - (index1 + 1)] = buffer[i];
        }
        scenarios[num][index2] = NULL;
    }


    std::cout << num << " 개의 시나리오가 있습니다." << endl;

    total = num;
    scen_file.close();
}


Map::Map(int* START_GOAL, char* IN_PATH, char* OUT_PATH, string MODE) {
    sx = START_GOAL[0];
    sy = START_GOAL[1];
    gx = START_GOAL[2];
    gy = START_GOAL[3];

    mode = MODE;

    in_path = IN_PATH;
    out_path = OUT_PATH;

    ifstream map_file(in_path);


    if (!map_file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "there is no map_file" << endl;
    }

    char buffer[128];
    char ch[4];
    char cw[4];

    map_file.getline(buffer, 128);


    map_file.getline(buffer, 128);
    for (int i = 7; i < strlen(buffer); i++) {
        ch[i - 7] = buffer[i];
    }
    h = atoi(ch);
    std::cout << "height = " << h << endl;;

    map_file.getline(buffer, 128);
    for (int i = 6; i < strlen(buffer); i++) {
        cw[i - 6] = buffer[i];
    }
    w = atoi(cw);
    std::cout << "width = " << w << endl;;

    map_file.getline(buffer, 128);

    std::cout << "Start at (" << sx << " " << sy << ")" << endl;
    std::cout << "Goal  is (" << gx << " " << gy << ")" << endl;
    std::cout << endl;

    in_map = new char*[h];
    direction_map = new int*[h];
    visit_map = new bool*[h];
    out_map = new char*[h];
    parent_map = new int*[h];
    open_node_map = new double*[h];


    for (int j = 0; j<h; j++) {
        in_map[j] = new char[w];
        direction_map[j] = new int[w];
        visit_map[j] = new bool[w];
        out_map[j] = new char[w];
        parent_map[j] = new int[w];
        open_node_map[j] = new double[w];

        for (int i = 0; i <= w; i++) {

            char tmp;
            map_file.get(tmp);

            if (w == i)
                continue;

            in_map[j][i] = tmp;
            direction_map[j][i] = -1;
            visit_map[j][i] = false;
            out_map[j][i] = tmp;
            open_node_map[j][i] = 0.0;
        }
    }

    map_file.close();
}

Map::~Map() {
    for (int i = 0; i<h; i++) {
        delete[] parent_map[i];
        delete[] in_map[i];
        delete[] direction_map[i];
        delete[] visit_map[i];
        delete[] out_map[i];
        delete[] open_node_map[i];
    }
    delete[] parent_map;
    delete[] in_map;
    delete[] direction_map;
    delete[] visit_map;
    delete[] out_map;
    delete[] open_node_map;
}

int Map::getGx() const { return gx; }
int Map::getGy() const { return gy; }
int Map::getSx() const { return sx; }
int Map::getSy() const { return sy; }

int Map::getHeight() const { return h; }
int Map::getWidth() const { return w; }
double Map::getOptimalLength() const { return optimal_length; }

char Map::getInMapData(int x, int y) { return in_map[y][x]; }
int Map::getDirectionData(int x, int y) { return direction_map[y][x]; }
bool Map::getVisitMapData(int x, int y) { return visit_map[y][x]; }
int Map::getParentMapData(int x, int y) { return parent_map[y][x]; }
double Map::getOpen_NodeData(int x, int y) { return open_node_map[y][x]; }


char Map::getOutMapData(int x, int y) const { return out_map[y][x]; }

void Map::setVisitMap(int x, int y, bool data) { visit_map[y][x] = data; }
void Map::setDirectionMap(int x, int y, int data) { direction_map[y][x] = data; }
void Map::setOutMap(int x, int y, char data) { out_map[y][x] = data; }
void Map::setParentMap(int x, int y, int data) { parent_map[y][x] = data; }
void Map::setOpen_NodeMap(int x, int y, double data) { open_node_map[y][x] = data; }


void Map::initialize() {}
void Map::draw_map() {

    ofstream out_file(out_path);

    for (int j = 0; j<h; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i<w; i++) {
            if (j == sy && i == sx)
                out_map[j][i] = 'S';

            if (j == gy && i == gx)
                out_map[j][i] = 'G';

            out_file << out_map[j][i];

        }
        out_file << "\r\n";
    }
    out_file.close();
}

void Map::A_star() {

    priority_queue<Node> search_q[2];

    Node startPoint(sx, sy, gx, gy, -1, 0, mode);
    int pqi = 0;
    search_q[pqi].push(startPoint);

    Map::setOpen_NodeMap(sx, sy, startPoint.getPriority());



    while (!search_q[pqi].empty()) {



        int cx = search_q[pqi].top().getX();    // current x, y
        int cy = search_q[pqi].top().getY();


        double passedLength_c = search_q[pqi].top().getPassedLength();

        Map::setVisitMap(cx, cy, true);
        Map::setOpen_NodeMap(cx, cy, search_q[pqi].top().getPriority());

        search_q[pqi].pop();


        if (cx == gx && cy == gy) {

            double shortestLength = 0;
            while (1) {


                if ((cx == sx) && (cy == sy)) break;

                int tmp_x, tmp_y, tmp_dir;
                tmp_x = cx;
                tmp_y = cy;
                tmp_dir = getDirectionData(tmp_x, tmp_y);

                cx -= DIR_X[tmp_dir];
                cy -= DIR_Y[tmp_dir];

                setOutMap(cx, cy, '#');

                if (tmp_dir % 2 == 1)
                    shortestLength += sqrt(2.0);
                else
                    shortestLength += 1.0;

            }

            cout << "A_star find!" << endl;
            cout << "Path Length = " << shortestLength << endl;
            optimal_length = shortestLength;


            while (!search_q[pqi].empty()) {
                search_q[pqi].pop();
            }

            return;
        }

        for (int dir = 0; dir<8; dir++) {
            // next_node
            int nx = cx + DIR_X[dir];
            int ny = cy + DIR_Y[dir];

            if (!(nx >(w - 1) || nx < 0 || ny >(h - 1) || ny < 0 || getInMapData(nx, ny) == '@' || getVisitMapData(nx, ny) == true)) {

                Node next_node(nx, ny, gx, gy, passedLength_c, dir, mode, 1);

                if (Map::getOpen_NodeData(nx, ny) == 0) {

                    Map::setOutMap(nx, ny, 'I');
                    Map::setOpen_NodeMap(nx, ny, next_node.getPriority());
                    search_q[pqi].push(next_node);
                    Map::setDirectionMap(nx, ny, dir);

                }

                else if (Map::getOpen_NodeData(nx, ny) > next_node.getPriority()) {


                    Map::setOpen_NodeMap(nx, ny, next_node.getPriority());
                    Map::setDirectionMap(nx, ny, dir);
                    search_q[pqi].push(next_node);
                    /*
                    while (!(search_q[pqi].top().getX() == nx && search_q[pqi].top().getY() == ny))
                    search_q[1 - pqi].push(search_q[pqi].top());
                    search_q[pqi].pop();
                    }
                    search_q[pqi].pop();

                    if (search_q[pqi].size() > search_q[1 - pqi].size()) {
                    pqi = 1 - pqi;
                    }
                    while (!search_q[pqi].empty()) {
                    search_q[1 - pqi].push(search_q[pqi].top());
                    search_q[pqi].pop();
                    }
                    pqi = 1 - pqi;
                    search_q[pqi].push(next_node);
                    */
                }


            }

        }

    }
}

void Map::JPS() {


    priority_queue <Node> JumpPoints;
    Node startPoint(sx, sy, gx, gy, 0, -1, mode, 1);

    startPoint.calculateDistanceToGoal();
    startPoint.updatePriority();

    JumpPoints.push(startPoint);


    while (!JumpPoints.empty()) {
        int x = JumpPoints.top().getX();
        int y = JumpPoints.top().getY();


        if (x == gx && y == gy) {
            cout << "JPS find!!!" << endl;

            double shortestLength = 0;
            while (!(x == Map::getSx() && y == Map::getSy())) {

                int fix_x = x;
                int fix_y = y;

                int tmp_dir = getDirectionData(fix_x, fix_y);


                int px = Map::getParentMapData(fix_x, fix_y) % 512;
                int py = Map::getParentMapData(fix_x, fix_y) / 512;


                //while(!(Map::getOutMapData(x, y) == 'J')){
                while (!(px == x && py == y)) {


                    if (Map::getParentMapData(fix_x, fix_y) == (y * Map::getWidth() + x)) break;

                    //if(!(Map::getOutMapData(x, y) == 'J')){
                    if (!(Map::getOutMapData(x, y) == 'J')) {
                        setOutMap(x, y, '#');
                    }

                    x -= DIR_X[tmp_dir];
                    y -= DIR_Y[tmp_dir];

                    if (tmp_dir % 2 == 1)
                        shortestLength += sqrt(2.0);
                    else
                        shortestLength += 1.0;

                }
            }
            optimal_length = shortestLength;
            cout << "Path Length = " << shortestLength << endl;
            //cout<<"Path Length = "<< passedLength_c << endl;

            return;
        }

        else
            Map::identifySuccessors(JumpPoints);


    }

    while (!JumpPoints.empty()) {
        JumpPoints.pop();
    }



    cout << "not found" << endl;

}

/*
Node Map::jump(Node const node, int dir, int& off) {
int nx = node.getX() + DIR_X[dir];
int ny = node.getY() + DIR_Y[dir];

if (nx > (w - 1) || nx < 0 || ny >(h - 1) || ny < 0) {
// Map::setOutMap(nx, ny, 'B');
Node NULL_node(-100, -100, 0, 0, 0, 0, "OCTILE", 1);
return NULL_node;
}
char n_MapData = Map::getOutMapData(nx, ny);

if (n_MapData == '@') {
Node NULL_node(-100, -100, 0, 0, 0, 0, "OCTILE", 1);
return NULL_node;
}
Node n_node(nx, ny, gx, gy, node.getPassedLength(), dir);

if (n_MapData == 'I')
Map::setOutMap(nx, ny, 'X');

if (nx == gx && ny == gy) {
off = 1;
return n_node;
}

int forced_neighbours_bits = Map::forced_neighbours(nx, ny, dir);

if (forced_neighbours_bits > 0) {
//Map::setOutMap(nx, ny, 'F');
return n_node;
}

if (dir % 2 == 1) {
// Algorithm 2 function jump 8th line)

if (Map::jump(n_node, (dir + 7) % 8, off).getX() != -100)
return n_node;

if (Map::jump(n_node, (dir + 1) % 8, off).getX() != -100)
return n_node;

}

if (n_MapData != 'S' && n_MapData != 'I' && n_MapData != 'G' && n_MapData != '@' && n_MapData != 'J')
Map::setOutMap(nx, ny, 'I');
//draw_map();


return Map::jump(n_node, dir, off);
}

*/



int Map::jump(int index, int dir, int& off) {

    int x = index % w;
    int y = index / w;


    int nx = x + DIR_X[dir];
    int ny = y + DIR_Y[dir];
    int n_index = ny * w + nx;

    if (nx > (w - 1) || nx < 0 || ny >(h - 1) || ny < 0) {
        // Map::setOutMap(nx, ny, 'B');     
        return -1;
    }
    char n_MapData = Map::getOutMapData(nx, ny);

    if (n_MapData == '@') {
        return -1;
    }

    if (n_MapData == 'I')
        Map::setOutMap(nx, ny, 'X');

    if (nx == gx && ny == gy) {
        off = 1;
        return n_index;
    }

    int forced_neighbours_bits = Map::forced_neighbours(nx, ny, dir);

    if (forced_neighbours_bits > 0) {
        //Map::setOutMap(nx, ny, 'F');
        return n_index;
    }

    if (dir % 2 == 1) {
        // Algorithm 2 function jump 8th line)

        if (Map::jump(n_index, (dir + 7) % 8, off) != -1)
            return n_index;

        if (Map::jump(n_index, (dir + 1) % 8, off) != -1)
            return n_index;

    }

    if (n_MapData != 'S' && n_MapData != 'I' && n_MapData != 'G' && n_MapData != '@' && n_MapData != 'J')
        Map::setOutMap(nx, ny, 'I');
    //draw_map();


    return Map::jump(n_index, dir, off);
}


void Map::identifySuccessors(priority_queue <Node>& successors) {


    int x = successors.top().getX();
    int y = successors.top().getY();



    if (x == gx && y == gy)
        return;

    int index = y * Map::getWidth() + x;

    int dir = successors.top().getDirection();
    double passedLength = successors.top().getPassedLength();



    Node start(x, y, gx, gy, passedLength, dir, mode, 1);

    start.updatePassedLength();
    start.calculateDistanceToGoal();
    start.updatePriority();

    successors.pop();

    vector<int> candidate_dir;
    if (dir == -1) {
        for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
            int dx = x + DIR_X[i];
            int dy = y + DIR_Y[i];
            if (!(dx < 0 || dx >(w - 1) || dy < 0 || dy >(h - 1) || Map::getOutMapData(dx, dy) == '@'))
                candidate_dir.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    else {
        int bits = Map::forced_neighbours(x, y, dir);
        for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
            if (bits & (1 << i))
                candidate_dir.push_back(i);
        }


        if (dir % 2 == 1) {
            int dx = x + DIR_X[(dir + 1) % 8];
            int dy = y + DIR_Y[(dir + 1) % 8];

            if (!(dx < 0 || dx >(w - 1) || dy < 0 || dy >(h - 1) || Map::getOutMapData(dx, dy) == '@'))
                candidate_dir.push_back((dir + 1) % 8);

            dx = x + DIR_X[(dir + 7) % 8];
            dy = y + DIR_Y[(dir + 7) % 8];

            if (!(dx < 0 || dx >(w - 1) || dy < 0 || dy >(h - 1) || Map::getOutMapData(dx, dy) == '@'))
                candidate_dir.push_back((dir + 7) % 8);

            dx = x + DIR_X[dir];
            dy = y + DIR_Y[dir];

            if (!(dx < 0 || dx >(w - 1) || dy < 0 || dy >(h - 1) || Map::getOutMapData(dx, dy) == '@'))
                candidate_dir.push_back(dir);
        }
        else {
            int dx = x + DIR_X[dir];
            int dy = y + DIR_Y[dir];
            if (!(dx < 0 || dx >(w - 1) || dy < 0 || dy >(h - 1) || Map::getOutMapData(dx, dy) == '@'))
                candidate_dir.push_back(dir);
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i<candidate_dir.size(); i++) {

        int nx, ny, n_index;
        int n_dir = candidate_dir[i];

        nx = x + DIR_X[n_dir];
        ny = y + DIR_Y[n_dir];


        int jx, jy;
        double  j_passedLength, s_dist = 0.0, d_dist = 0.0;


        int off = 0;
        int j_index = Map::jump(index, n_dir, off);

        if (j_index == -1)
            continue;

        jx = j_index % w;
        jy = j_index / w;
        j_passedLength = passedLength + sqrt((x - jx)*(x - jx) + (y - jy)*(y - jy));

        Node j_node(jx, jy, gx, gy, j_passedLength, n_dir, mode, 1);

        j_node.setPassedLength(j_passedLength);
        j_node.calculateDistanceToGoal();
        j_node.updatePriority();

        if (Map::getOpen_NodeData(jx, jy) == 0) {

            Map::setOutMap(jx, jy, 'J');
            Map::setParentMap(jx, jy, y * Map::getWidth() + x);

            Map::setDirectionMap(jx, jy, n_dir);
            Map::setOpen_NodeMap(jx, jy, j_node.getPriority());
            successors.push(j_node);
        }

        else if (Map::getOpen_NodeData(jx, jy) > j_node.getPriority()) {
            Map::setOpen_NodeMap(jx, jy, j_node.getPriority());
            Map::setDirectionMap(jx, jy, n_dir);

            Map::setParentMap(jx, jy, y * Map::getWidth() + x);

        }



    }

    candidate_dir.clear();
    return;
    cout << "not found" << endl;
}


/*
*/
bool Map::is_obstacle(int x, int y, int dir) {
    int nx = x + DIR_X[dir];
    int ny = y + DIR_Y[dir];

    if (nx < 0 || nx >(w - 1) || ny < 0 || ny >(h - 1))
        return false;

    if (Map::getInMapData(nx, ny) == '@')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int Map::forced_neighbours(int x, int y, int dir) {
    int bits = 0;

    if (dir == -1)
        return -1;

    if (dir % 2 == 0) {
        // straight
        int ndir1 = (dir + 2) % 8;
        int ndir2 = (dir + 6) % 8;

        if (Map::is_obstacle(x, y, ndir1)) {
            if (!Map::is_obstacle(x, y, (dir + 1) % 8))
                bits = bits | 1 << ((dir + 1) % 8);
        }
        if (Map::is_obstacle(x, y, ndir2))
            if (!Map::is_obstacle(x, y, (dir + 7) % 8))
                bits = bits | 1 << ((dir + 7) % 8);
    }
    else {
        int ndir1 = (dir + 3) % 8;
        int ndir2 = (dir + 5) % 8;

        if (Map::is_obstacle(x, y, ndir1))
            if (!Map::is_obstacle(x, y, (dir + 1) % 8))
                bits = bits | 1 << ((dir + 1) % 8);
        if (Map::is_obstacle(x, y, ndir2))
            if (!Map::is_obstacle(x, y, (dir + 7) % 8))
                bits = bits | 1 << ((dir + 7) % 8);
    }
    return bits;
}

Node::Node(int const x, int const y, int const gx, int const gy, double const passedLength, int const direction, string const mode, int const k) {
    this->x = x; this->y = y;

    this->direction = direction;
    this->passedLength = passedLength;
    this->gx = gx; this->gy = gy;
    this->mode = mode;

    if (k == 1) {

        updatePassedLength();
        calculateDistanceToGoal();
        updatePriority();
    }
}

Node::~Node() {}

int Node::getX() const { return x; }
int Node::getY() const { return y; }
int Node::getDirection() const { return direction; }
double Node::getPriority() const { return priority; }
double Node::getPassedLength() const { return passedLength; }
double Node::getDistanceToGoal() const { return distanceToGoal; }

void Node::calculateDistanceToGoal() {

    double xd = abs(x - gx);
    double yd = abs(y - gy);

    if (mode.compare("MANHATTAN") == 0)
        distanceToGoal = abs(xd) + abs(yd);

    else if (mode.compare("EUCLIDIAN") == 0)
        distanceToGoal = sqrt((xd*xd) + (yd*yd));

    else if (mode.compare("CHEBYSHEV") == 0)
        distanceToGoal = max(abs(xd), abs(yd));

    else if (mode.compare("OCTILE") == 0)
        distanceToGoal = max(xd, yd) + (sqrt(2.0) - 1) + min(xd, yd);

    else
        cout << "plz input mode" << endl;

}



void Node::updatePassedLength() {

    if (direction == -1);

    else if (direction % 2 == 1)
        passedLength += (sqrt(2.0));
    else
        passedLength += (1);
}

void Node::updatePriority() {
    priority = passedLength + distanceToGoal;
}

void Node::setPassedLength(double data) {
    passedLength = data;
}
```

util.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class Node {

private:
    int x;
    int y;

    int gx;
    int gy;

    int direction;      // direction from past node
    double passedLength;
    double distanceToGoal;
    double priority;
    string mode;        // mode -> "MANHATTAN", "EUCLIDIAN", CHEBYSHEV", "OCTILE"

public:

    Node(int const x, int const y, int const gx, int const gy, double const passedLength, int const direction = 0,  string const mode = "MANHATTAN" , int const k = 0 );
    ~Node();
    int getX() const;
    int getY() const;
    int getDirection() const;

    double getPriority() const;
    double getPassedLength() const;
    double getDistanceToGoal() const;

    void setPassedLength(double data);

    void calculateDistanceToGoal();
    void updatePassedLength();
    void updatePriority();

};


class Map {

public:
    int gx, gy, sx, sy, w, h;
    char* in_path, *out_path;
    string mode;

    char** in_map;
    int** direction_map;
    bool** visit_map;
    char** out_map;
    int** parent_map;
    double** open_node_map;
    double optimal_length;

public:
    Map(int* START_GOAL, char* IN_PATH, char* OUT_PATH, string MODE);
    ~Map();

    int getGx() const;
    int getGy() const;
    int getSx() const;
    int getSy() const;


    char getInMapData(int x, int y);
    int getDirectionData(int x, int y);
    bool getVisitMapData(int x, int y);
    int getParentMapData(int x, int y);
    double getOpen_NodeData(int x, int y);

    int getHeight() const;
    int getWidth() const;
    double getOptimalLength() const;

    char getOutMapData(int x, int y) const;

    void setVisitMap(int x, int y, bool data);
    void setDirectionMap(int x, int y, int data);
    void setOutMap(int x, int y, char data);
    void setParentMap(int x, int y, int data);
    void setOpen_NodeMap(int x, int y, double data);

    void initialize();
    void draw_map();

    void A_star();
    void JPS();

    //int identifySuccessors(int x, int y);



    void identifySuccessors(priority_queue <Node>& successors);
    //int jump(int node_index, int dir, double& s_distance, priority_queue <Node>& successors, double& d_distance, int& trig, int& fx_fy);
    //Node Map::jump(Node node, int dir, int& off);
    int Map::jump(int index, int dir, int& off);

    bool is_obstacle(int x, int n, int dir);
    int Map::forced_neighbours(int x, int y, int dir);


};


void read_scenario(char* path, char(*scenarios)[256], int& total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without an individual review of each line of code, it appears that the speed difference is due to your programming style.

To take just the first two examples: `vector_clear` is a poor reimplementation of `std::vector::clear` and `operator<(Node a, Node b)` makes unnecessary copies of both nodes. And glancing at the rest of the code, these do not appear to be exceptions.

Measuring the speed of a debug executable is pointless. The compiler settings used for debugging do not take speed of the resulting executable into account. And you've further complicated it by using a debug version of new. Only the speed in release mode is reasonable, and then only if you have good code to start with.